# Sci fi anthology book with a story about a lizard alien who comes to Earth, and another about a commune of humans being led by tentacle aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, horror, anthology-book

I am looking for a book -- I think from the '70s or '80s -- that was a collection of scifi stories that usually had some kind of horror element to them.

I know the first story was about a man who could hear something burrowing below his house and it slowly drives him mad. It ends with the worm burrowing into his house and eating him.

There was also a story about a lizard alien from a collapsed civilization on Mars or Venus that comes to Earth and is eventually killed by the military.

The only other story I remember involved a post-apocalyptic Earth setting where a small commune of humans interacted with these tentacle aliens that were their leaders.

I think there was another story about a plague that turned things into dust, but I am not sure.

The cover had a bunch of aliens on it; I remember one was green and humanoid and another was orange.

Comment: Welcome to SF&F Stack Exchange!  Please be sure to take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ].  Meantime, where did you read this, and in what language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that the first story is "The Worm" (described well in the answer to this old question [Name of the book that carried a short story about a man living in a windmill/grinder attacked by giant worm?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85758/28516)) and your description of the cover

> The cover had a bunch of aliens on it; I remember one was green and humanoid and another was orange.

I will propose "[Creatures from Beyond](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?8216)" as the anthology.

[image]

(image from isfdb.org link)

I actually own this book, but it's 1000 miles away, so I can't id the other stories.

**Edit** by user14111:

The story about a lizard alien from a dead civilization on Venus who comes to Earth and is killed by the military is ["Beauty and the Beast"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71389) by Henry Kuttner, which you can read at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v16n01_1940-04.Better/page/n65/mode/2up?view=theater).

The story about a community of humans on postapocalyptic Earth interacting with tentacled Martians is the famous classic ["Dear Devil"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41498) by Eric Frank Russell, which you can also read at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/other-worlds-v-01n-04-1950-05/mode/2up).

The story "about a plague that turned things into dust" may be a garbled recollection of "The Street That Wasn't There" a.k.a ["The Lost Street"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56955) by Carl Jacobi and Clifford W. Simak, which you can read in the anthology *Creatures from Beyond*, which you can borrow (free but registration required) from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/creaturesfrombey0000unse). In this story the Earth is indeed ravaged by a worldwide plague, and buildings and things are not turning into dust but disappearing into thin air and being replaced by something strange. An excerpt:

> A tumultuous idea hammered at him. Men had died by the millions all over the world. Where there had been thousands of minds there now were one or two. A feeble force to hold the form of matter intact. The plague had swept Europe and Asia almost clear of life, had blighted Africa, had reached South America—might even have come to the United States. He remembered the whispers he had heard, the words of the men at the drugstore corner, the buildings disappearing. Something scientists could not explain. But those were merely scraps of information. He did not know the whole story . . . he could not know. He never listened to the radio, never read a newspaper.
>
> But abruptly the whole thing fitted together in his brain like the missing piece of a puzzle into its slot. The significance of it all gripped him with damning clarity. There were not sufficient minds in existence to retain the material world in its mundane form. Some other power from another dimension was fighting to supersede man's control *and take his universe into its own plane!*

Comment: That's it, thank you so much!

Comment: @ElaineAnspach You're welcome, and welcome to the site.  Please mark the answer as correct by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of it! Feel free to upvote it as well if you like :)

Comment: I should have a copy of that book in my basement. If you don't mind I'll try to ID the other stories and edit them into your answer.

Comment: @user14111 please do!